# Spring MVC internatialization

Tags: java, spring, internationalization

I'm trying to use internatialization in my spring mvc application. 
But I can't get how to use it for inputs.
I want to do smth like this:

```
<input id="actionButton" type="submit" value='<spring:message code="LogIn"/>'/>
```

But the button than has label 'spring:message code="LogIn"', not the value of this constant from .properties file. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you have your locale interceptor configured correctly?

Comment: Yes, if I use spring:message not as value for input, everything works.

Comment: Have you considered storing the spring:message content to a var and then referencing that var with $ from EL?

Comment: Is it the only aproach? I think it is not good..what if I have 10 buttons..I'll have to set 10 variables.

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot use a tag inside another tag, so this is what first came to mind.

Comment: Try also: value="<spring:message code="LogIn"/>"

Comment: I've tried:) Result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered storing the spring:message content to a var and then referencing that var with $?

A very useful tutorial is here: http://springbyexample.org/examples/basic-webapp-internationalization.html

You must have an interceptor in applicationContext like

```
<mvc:interceptors>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
        </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

You also need

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver"/>
```

I would also like to add that at the beginning of your xml you should have stuff like:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">
```

It is necessary in order to recognize the prefixes such as mvc. Make sure you have it.

My messages_*.properties files are in a source folder src/main/resources, not in webapp, I don't know if this matters.

Comment: Yes, that's just what I havу :)